# Singular, all-encompassing UnitOfWork vs. mutliple, smaller UnitOfWork abstractions?

Tags: design-patterns, tdd, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, solid-principles

I'm building a data access layer for a web application and am trying to figure out whether I should use a singular Unit Of Work (UoW) to track all my database activity (regardless of whether I use all or few of the `IRepository<T>`'s containted therein), or create smaller Units of Work based around a specific workflow (`UserUnitOfWork`, `SchedulesUnitOfWork` etc).

I am wondering if a large UoW would violate the Single Responsibility principle, as my database is less likely to change than a conventional POCO object (I'm coding in C#, but that probably isn't so relevant here). If I had a flow that needed to make multiple changes to the database, it would probably be better to create a large UoW, as I won't have to `.Commit()` for every UoW instance, but just once.

If I base my smaller UoWs around a specific 'flow', then there is often the case where I have overlapping concrete repository classes (`SqlRepository<User>` could be used quite frequently, for example). This code duplication is obviously a DRY violation, but it would mean that my smaller UoWs are easier to read, navigate and change.

Does this simply come down to a design decision? Are there any trade-offs between smaller/larger UoWs? What would the impact on testability be when choosing one of the other? Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you ask this question differently if you thought "db transactions" instead of UoW? I have a problem figuring out what you perceive as the problem with big or small UoW. It sounds like you have concerns more about the maintenance of the code, not the actual UoW stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @gurun. I'm thinking of this as both 'db transactions', but also as a class object. With a large database, a singular UoW would get quite large, difficult to navigate etc., but it would allow me to bundle all my transactions together and require only ever one `.Commit()` call. If I broke it up, my code would be more manageable and violate less OO rules but require more calls to `.Commit()`. I think a larger UoW would be more efficient in terms of manipulating data, but not in terms of design and best practices. Am I right? If I am, which is generally better?

Answer (score 0):

The true architect answer would be "it depends".

I will provide you with **my own way of thinking** about these things in the cases when code turns to abstract to think about. It will be a non-typical SO answer for sure. Let's see how many down votes I get.

Try to think of this as people, and groups of people, and pretend that your are trying to learn something new. It turns into a coordination issue.

In the case you are the only one learning, and your time is more important than all other peoples/groups the most effective way for you to ask questions is to have all people in the same room as you, so you can ask questions and get answered immediately.

In he case you are the only one learning, but your time is less or equally worth everybody else's time, you would be forced to split the answering group into small groups, and structure your learning process. In his case you would have the chance to ask questions around a specific scenario to a specific group.

Now apply this to multiple people learning the same thing. In that case you can either collect all the learning people in the sake room and learn together with all resources answering in the room at the same time. This is a typical conference room panel Q&A session.

Apply it to multiple people learning the same thing, structure the learning, and have the people answering only a specific part in the room at the same time. Typical class room setup.

And then a final variant, where you have learning stations. The people learning can walk around different stations asking questions to each station. Each station is occupied by people answer questions based on different scenarios.

Then translate this to transactions and units of work. Thing people asking questions as requests, and people answering them as resources (like DB). The person organizing this is of course the transaction coordinator.

I think you will find that it turns into a cost benefit calculation. The cost of locking up resources, and the benefit of having resources available when you need them. Hence the only real answer to this is "it depends".

**Opinion:** In general, I would say that the most effective way of learning without wasting resources would be to use do a breakdown of the learning process into separate activities, have answering stations based on scenarios, and make sure the people answering questions are free to do other work while waiting for someone asking questions. And in the end, you might want to order the sequence of the stations to make sure all people don't go to the same station at the sake time. And if they do, maybe consider an other learning process from above.

And that to me translates to keeping the UoW as small and isolated as possible. If it makes sense (for the system in question) to do classroom style, consider batching. If cost/performance is not an issue, do large UoW because it might make it easier to maintain. And lastly, if cost is really not an issue but you need serious throughout do panel style and both batch and do large UoW.